# how we can get html control if any which are placed inside RadEditor

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I want to find out how we can get html control if any which are placed inside RadEditor and replace that value. I have try this way to change the Image source.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function getEditor()
 {
    editor = $find("<%=reFormEditor.ClientID%>"); //return a reference to RadEditor
    var image = editor.get_document().body.document.getElementById("Image1");
}
```

Here is my aspx:

```
 <telerik:RadEditor runat="server" ID="reFormEditor">
<Content>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit2" runat="server" Text="Submit"/>
<img id="Image1" src="../Images/tabSelected.jpg" />
</Content>
</telerik:RadEditor>
```

I want to change the Image source when  textbox keydown. Help me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code, and you can't put button inside contents it must be outside of editor contents :

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function replaceImage() {
      var editor = $find("<%= reFormEditor.ClientID %>");
      var oDocument = editor.get_document()
      var img = oDocument.getElementById('imageInContents');
      img.src = '/image2.png';
    }  
  </script> 
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="mika" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <telerik:RadEditor runat="server" ID="reFormEditor">
    <Content>
      <img id="imageInContents" src="/image1.png" />
    </Content>
    </telerik:RadEditor>
    <input type="button" onclick="replaceImage()" value="Replace Image" /> 
    </form>
</body>
```

And here is an example with text change

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function replaceSpanText() {
      var editor = $find("<%= reFormEditor.ClientID %>");
      var oDocument = editor.get_document()
      var spn = oDocument.getElementById('span1');
      spn.innerHTML = 'Text 2';
    }  
  </script> 
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="mika" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <telerik:RadEditor runat="server" ID="reFormEditor">
    <Content>
      <span id="span1">Text 1</span>
    </Content>
    </telerik:RadEditor>
    <input type="button" onclick="replaceSpanText()" value="Replace text" /> 
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: when I use like that I am getting Error Image1 is not exist .

Comment: sorry, I overlooked that you didn't use ASP.NET image control, that submit button confused me, you know that that button will not render and in fact it doesnt do nothing. I will update my answer

Comment: Thank yoy for your Code it worked fine but actual my requirement is I have asp lable inside content I want to replace that lable value when text box text change. for that I have write this way but It is not worked please help me

Comment: you can't have ASP.NET Label in rad editor contents, but you can have <span> tag for example with ID and get that element just like the image in example, and then set it's innerHtml. I will add this example to my answer

Comment: Thank you Antonio it is working fine for me .Is there any way to load More Than two span tags with specific location dynamicallay. For Example nedd to load spantag given x and y locations dynamically inside radeditor .

Comment: you just need set different ID's to span tags and find it with getElementById and then set it's innerHTML

Comment: Antonio I want load Span tag in rad editor Content Programatically

Comment: Venkateswararao, look at this link http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-pastehtml.html and please open a new question if you have any problems with this